# soft keypad for 'phone edit text' dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

I am building an application where I want to show only numbers keypad i.e 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 digits dynamically.That number keypad is being used for the field name 'phone number'. I have the solution but that works in a static way..but my phone field is dynamic,now I am using

```
phoneText.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener(true, true));
```

method,but this method shows total numeric soft keypad..and I want only numbers to be displayed..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried?

```
phoneText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```

Answer (score 1):

use this..

```
android:inputType="phone"
```

for dynamic

```
    EditText et = new EditText(this);
 et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE);
```